# Can I create a shortcut for Paste Features As?

Tags: qgis-3

Is there any way to create a shortcut to "Paste Features As", or even better "Paste Features As->Temporary Layer"? It's not in the list for Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut for this operation is already defined by default since QGIS version 3.10.4 and it is `Ctrl+Alt+V`.

[image]

If you want to customise the shortcut or set it in the previous QGIS versions, you can find it in the *Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts list* as *Temporary Scratch Layer*.

Comment: what version are you working with? That shortcut is not present in 3.4.2 on Windows.

Comment: I am using the current LTR 3.10.4. But I can see that the shortcut is already present in the old LTR 3.14. I have just checked 3.4.2 and the shortcut it is not by default. You can anyway set it in the Setting->Keyboard Shortcuts using the voice Temporary Scratch Layer. I have updated the answer to clarify the different QGIS versions condition.